# How many ways are there to choose subsets $S$ and $T$ of $A=\{1,2,3,,.....,n\}$ so that $S$ contains $T$?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, analysis, solution-verification, combinations

How many ways are there to choose subsets $S$ and $T$ of $A=\{1,2,3,,.....,n\}$ so that $S$ contains $T$?

My attempt :

The number of all subsets of $A$ is $2^n$. Let's denote this subsets by $S_{\alpha}$ ,where $\alpha$ is the size of each subset

so $S=[S_0 ,S_1 ,S_2 ,...,S_n ]$

Suppose we choose $S_3$ so we must to choose a subset T of this $S_3$ for having that $S_3$ contain T, and the number of T in this case is $2^3$, but we must to note that there are ${ n \choose 3}$ of this $S_3$, so the number of ways to choose a $S_3$ and T such that $S_3$ contain T is ${n \choose 3}\cdot2^3$

and we will the same thing for each $S_{\alpha}$

for example for $S_{12}$, the number of ways to choose a $S_{12}$ and T such that $S_{12}$ contain T is ${n \choose 12}\cdot2^{12}$

and so on

so the answer is that: ${n \choose 0}\cdot2^{0}+{n \choose 1}\cdot2^{1}+{n \choose 2}\cdot2^{2}+....{n \choose n}\cdot2^{n}$

and that's equal: $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}\cdot2^{k}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}\cdot2^{k}\cdot1^{n-k}=(1+2)^n=3^n$

What do you think about my answer?

Comment: +1 to your question.  Very nice analysis.  Although I could be mistaken, I think that your answer is correct.  Personally, my first instinct was to reverse the analysis, looking at each possible subset $T$, and for each such subset, enumerating the number of possible supersets $S$.  On reflection, I think that your approach is superior to what would have been my first try.

Comment: Your result is correct. More simply: For each element of $A$, there are $3$ option: In $S$, in $S$ and $T$, or in neither. $\implies 3^n$

Answer (score 1):

*Just so this is answered:*

$3^n$ is correct.

- Your choosing $k$ items for the larger subset giving $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} 2^k =(1+2)^n=3^n$ works
- Daniel Mathias's suggestion each element is in neither subset, or only in the larger subset, or in both, gives the same result